# Javascript/CSS not working as expected, elements not displaying/updating

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

This script enables the user to create a circle centered on a marker, with possibility to change the circle diameter interactively. There is an issue in the HTML below.

The range bar and associated filling frame is the only element displayed when I launch this html in a navigator (Chrome). ALso, the value in frame is not updated when I change the value using range bar.

I think the issue has to do with the integration of CSS and Javascript. But I cannot see what is wrong.

```js
function map() {
    let set = 10;
    let zoom = 9;
    let circles;
    let entreprise = [43.600000, 1.433333];
    let mymap = L.map('mapid').setView(entreprise, zoom);

    let osmLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        maxZoom: 18
    });

    mymap.addLayer(osmLayer);
    L.marker(entreprise).addTo(mymap);

    // On retranscrit la valeur du input range dans le input Number (et inversement)
    $('.range').on('input', function() {
        set = $(this).val();
        $('.kilometres').val(set);
    });

    $('.kilometres').on('input', function() {
        set = $(this).val();
        $('.range').val(set);
    });

    circles = L.circle(entreprise, 1000*set, {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).addTo(mymap);

    $( ".range, .kilometres" ).on('input', function() {
        if(mymap.hasLayer(circles))
            mymap.removeLayer(circles);

        circles = L.circle(entreprise, 1000*set, {
            color: 'red',
            fillColor: '#f03',
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }).addTo(mymap);
    });
}
    
map();
```

```css
div.row {
   width: 700px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

div > input {
   display: block;
   width: 300px;
   margin: 10px;
}

#mapid {
     height: 250px;
     width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
      <input type="number" class="kilometres" name="kilometres" min="0" max="100" placeholder="15" value="15" />
      <input type="range" class="range" name="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="15" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div id="mapid"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in codepen. What is the exact issue you're facing? What isn't working as expected?

Comment: Range bar and associated filling frame is the only element displayed when I launch this html in a navigator (Chrome).

Comment: In addition, value in frame is not updated when I move value on using range bar.

Comment: In the future, please provide all the info in the question itself, not in comments. And always describe exactly what is going wrong, rather than just giving us code and making us guess.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you're missing some script imports. You require `wrld.js` `jQuery.js` and `leaflet.css` for this to work.

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title>Circle variable</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Import Leaflet.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.1/leaflet.css">
    
    <style>
         div.row {
             width: 700px;
             margin: 0 auto;
         }

         div > input {
             display: block;
             width: 300px;
             margin: 10px;
          }

          #mapid {
               height: 250px;
               width: 300px;
          } 
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
          <input type="number" class="kilometres" name="kilometres" min="0" max="100" placeholder="15" value="15" />
          <input type="range" class="range" name="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="15" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div id="mapid"></div>
      </div>
  </div>

<!-- Import jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.2/jquery.min.js">

<!-- Import Wrld 3d -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/wrld.js@1.x.x">

<script>
function map() {
    let set = 10;
    let zoom = 9;
    let circles;
    let entreprise = [43.600000, 1.433333];
    let mymap = L.map('mapid').setView(entreprise, zoom);

    let osmLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        maxZoom: 18
    });

    mymap.addLayer(osmLayer);
    L.marker(entreprise).addTo(mymap);

    // On retranscrit la valeur du input range dans le input Number (et inversement)
    $('.range').on('input', function() {
        set = $(this).val();
        $('.kilometres').val(set);
    });

    $('.kilometres').on('input', function() {
        set = $(this).val();
        $('.range').val(set);
    });

    circles = L.circle(entreprise, 1000*set, {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).addTo(mymap);

    $( ".range, .kilometres" ).on('input', function() {
        if(mymap.hasLayer(circles))
            mymap.removeLayer(circles);

        circles = L.circle(entreprise, 1000*set, {
            color: 'red',
            fillColor: '#f03',
            fillOpacity: 0.5
        }).addTo(mymap);
    });
}
    
map();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I added the lines below, but it does not work well. Is script version issuing ?                                                                                      
                   <meta charset='utf-8' />
 <script src="https://cdn-webgl.wrld3d.com/wrldjs/dist/latest/wrld.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.1/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Copy them form my code above. Both scripts below the CLOSING `</body>` tag.
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.2/jquery.min.js">`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/wrld.js@1.x.x">` and the style in the `<head>` tag: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.1/leaflet.css">`

Comment: Any idea about what is wrong ?

Comment: When I trigger html below on any navigator, no circle is displayed

Comment: I won't be able to tell without actually seeing the page. It works no problem in codepen, so must be a problem with your imports. https://codepen.io/j0r_dan/pen/wvxMoMy?